# want to set value in one activity and display it on the button of another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities (Activity 1) and (activity 3) in my program. I want to set String in activity3 take that String value and set it on a button in Activity1. How should I do that ?

Below code is in my Activity 1 -

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
    String label = intent.getStringExtra("Channel Label");
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button.setText(label);
```

Below code is in my activity 3 -

```
 View.OnClickListener Save = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity3.this, Activity1.class);
            EditText label = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label);
            intent.putExtra("Channel Label", label.getText());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

replace label.getText() with label.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

Your code in activity 3 should be like

```
 View.OnClickListener Save = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity3.this, Activity1.class);
        EditText label = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label);
        intent.putExtra("message", label.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

And receive it like

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  String message = bundle.getString("message");
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
  button.setText(""+message+"");
```

Comment: I changed it but still cannot see the value(label) getting displayed on that button in Activity 1.

Comment: try now. i have edited it. and it works for me @Sarica

Comment: Its showing "NULL" as a value(label) to that button now. If I try to enter a value in the editext field in activity 3, it should take that value and set on that button in Activity 1. For eg: if I give ABC as a label in activity3 then the same label(ABC) should be displayed on button in Activity 1.

Comment: Yes I used your code. If you given a label name can you see the same label name in Activity 1 with your code? coz I cant see :( on my side its showing NULL on that button.

Comment: in activity check if u get value from label correctly

Comment: yes its correct. I replaced my code with your code.